# Using UITouch To Drag A UITextField Around The Screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitouch

I am developing a sample application, where I have a situation for moving a UITextFields, UILabels etc., across the screen. I am not able to find any resource for implementing this.

I want to implement like [this](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/) for a UITextField

Comment: if any answer helps you to solve your problem then accept the answer by clicking the checkmark it which is a standard practice in  SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an excellent tutorial on dragging already, I will assume your problem is the keyboard that comes up when you try to drag a UITextField instead of a UIView. The solution should be pretty simple: `myTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` - that should disable user interaction and make it "read only". Perhaps have an edit mode where all text fields get this flag set. If it causes trouble, then add the textField to a UIView and then set the userInteractionEnabled to false. Then you can drag the UIView and it will drag the text field with it.

Comment: Thanks Michael i will try this and get back to you ASAP

Comment: Michael thanks i got the solution,i have posted my code for reference.Bye...Take Care..

Answer (score 2):

I followed Michael's suggestion and got the solution.I have given the code snippets below which will be useful for those who need to implement the same.

**Steps:**

Choose windows based application,then create a UIViewController subclass and add it to the window in the appdelegate file.

In the XIB of the viewcontroller class you created add UIViews and add the controls like textfield etc.,to the UIViews that you have created.We are going to move these views only,so add IBOutlets in the .h file of the view controller subclass and map them to the IB accordingly.

**Sample Code**

**appdelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyView.h"

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
MyView *viewController;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

**appdelegate.m**

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"


@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    viewController=[[MyView alloc]init];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyView : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *textFieldView;
    IBOutlet UIView *labelView;

}

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "MyView.h"


@implementation MyView


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.view addSubview:textFieldView];
    [self.view addSubview:labelView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // get touch event
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([touch view] == textFieldView) {
        // move the image view
        textFieldView.center = touchLocation;
    }
    if ([touch view] == labelView) {
        // move the image view
        labelView.center = touchLocation;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Thank u all.Have a niece time.